# start a function if another function is active and activate some checkboxes only - JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

i Have a function that I want to start only if another function is previously activated.

I have some CheckBoxes and I need to sum its values to get the total.

Only When a user has selected some of the CheckBoxes it must activate another checkbox with a discount.
I want that the discount checkbox get activated after the first selection because, if I don't do so, I could have a negative price.

Then (if it's possible) I want that the discount checkbox get deactivated is a user deselect all the previous CheckBoxes.

Is this possible?

Here's my script. I'm super new in JavaScript/jQuery so this might be a stupid question.

Thank you

```js
$(document).on('change', getCheck);
  
  function getCheck() {
    var total= 0;
    $('[type="checkbox"]:checked').not("#discount").each(function(i, el) {
    //console.log($(this).not("#off").val());
    var SumVehicle = parseFloat($(el).val());
    total += SumVehicle;
    //console.log(total);
    //console.log(price_tot);
    $('#rata').text(total  +" €");

     var finalprice = total;
     //var Check = getCheck();
         
        if(typeof(total) != "undefined" && total !== 0) {
          $('[type="checkbox"]:checked').not(".sum").each(function(i, el) {
          var Discount = parseFloat($(this).val());
          finalprice = finalprice - Discount;
          console.log(finalprice);
          $('#rata').text(finalprice  +" €");
          });
        };
      });
    };
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="sum" type="checkbox" name="vehicle1" value="1000"> I have a bike<br>
<input class="sum" type="checkbox" name="vehicle2" value="2000"> I have a car<br>
<br><br><br>
<input id="discount" type="checkbox" name="discount" value="200"> Discount<br>

<div id="rata">rata</div>
```

Comment: There is an error in you js code. Please edit and fix that

Comment: One thing that's very important in javascript is to check the developer console for errors and debugging. For example, the console of the script  you posted has an error. Press `F12` on the browser to access this console log

Comment: Set the `disabled` property of the `discount` checkbox depending on whether it should be activated.

Comment: Thanks to all, i might have solved!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your js code with this code. the error will be resolved.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $("input[type='checkbox']").on('change', getCheck);

  });
  function getCheck() {
    var total= 0;
    $('[type="checkbox"]:checked').not("#discount").each(function(i, el) {
    console.log($(this).not("#off").val());
    var SumVehicle = parseFloat($(el).val());
    total += SumVehicle;
    console.log(total);
    //console.log(price_tot);
    $('#rata').html(total  +" €");

     var finalprice = total;
     var Check = function getCheck(){

        if(typeof(Check) != "undefined" && Check !== null) {
          $("#discount").toggle(); 
          var Discount = parseFloat($(this).val());
          finalprice -= Discount;
          console.log(finalprice);
          $('#rata').text(finalprice  +" €");

        };
      };
    });
  };
```